# Stuck at elementaryOS logo after shutdown

Tags: shutdown

using the latest version Hera 5.1 of eOS, when I shutdown my computer the screen stay at the logo forever.
I tried "sudo shutdown now" but nothing change.
Also tried Esc but it show nothing. (Nothing change it stay at the logo)

I always have to shutdown manually by pressing the power button.
Thanks by advance for the help!

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by **but it show nothing**. It is a black screen with nothing on it, or a list of commands but you do not found anything wrong?

Comment: Got the same issue. The screen keep showing the logo but the computer takes for ever to shutdown sometimes. But it usually works. Started to look for an issue, I have Elementary installed on a SSD with EXT4 and journaling, could this be a a lead ?